# Linux UI framework to framebuffer with custom RGB manipulation

Tags: linux, qt, framebuffer

I have a device I am developing that processes the CPU output (over HDMI) in a propietary, non RGB, but 24 bit, format. The device vendor is providing me a method that will convert the RGB into their format.

With that said, I would like to use a UI framework supports writing to the framebuffer, but also allow me to intercept the RGB data before it is sent to the framebuffer.

I know QT supports framebuffer, but does it allow me to intercept the output before adding it to the framebuffer?

Maybe a gaming library (java? python?) that allows me to do this?

Comment: Your question leaves me confused: Is your application reading video data from this proprietary device, or is your application creating video data that will be sent to the proprietary device for display?

Comment: I will be creating video data (video overlay) to a proprietary device. HDMI doesn't support alpha channels, so the vendor is proving custom methods to encode RGBA over RGB (HDMI), by increasing the resolution to account for additional alpha channel), and then decreasing the resolution and gaining back the alpha channel in the hardware.